# Fractions: Sum and difference in C programming

Tags: c, fractions

I'm facing problems in writing a program in C that calculates S, being S = {1/50 - 3/48 + 5/46...} with 9 elements. I don't know how to use the DIFFERENCE operator followed by a SUM operator, and I MUST use the **for** structure.

Here's the program I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    int n, d, S, i;
    i = 0;
    n = 1;
    d = 50;
    S = n / ((double)d);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        n += 2;
        n -= 2;
        S = S + (n / ((double)d));
        S = S - (n / ((double)d));
    }
    printf("%d", S);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the variable declarations may be wrong and that's exactly where I get confused. I decalred S as an integer but put d (denominator) to double 'cause the result must be a decimal number, of course.

Can anybody help me??

The output I'm getting is: `0`

Comment: You want to step through the code inside a debugger while inspecting all relevant variables to learn what is going on.

Comment: If `S` is an `int` then it is an integer.  an integer can only be a whole number.

Comment: `n+=2;
   n-=2;` does not makes sense. `n` does not change in the end. This is a NOP. The same applies to those two statements: `S = S + (n/((double)d));
   S = S - (n/((double)d));`

Comment: You want 9 elements, but your loop only executes 4 times.

Comment: MUST is also an operator? or why is it in capital letters ?

Comment: @stark She uses a loop of 4 because she is attempting to handle two terms for each loop index, with the initial term handled outside the loop.

Comment: All of your variables (except `i`) should be `double`. And the `n-=2` should be `d-=2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this. The most important point, is to use the `double` type, because the `int` type can only hold whole numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int i;
    double sign = 1.0;              // sign
    double num = 1.0;               // numerator
    double div = 50.0;              // divisor
    double sum = 0.0;               // series sum

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        sum += sign * num / div;    // accumulate the term
        num += 2.0;                 // numerator +2
        div -= 2.0;                 // divisor -2
        sign *= -1.0;               // alternate the sign
        printf("%f\n", sum);        // show double result
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
0.020000
-0.042500
0.066196
-0.092895
0.121390
-0.153610
0.188496
-0.228171
0.271829
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if what you're looking for is the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main () {
    int n = 1, d = 50, i = 0, signal = 1;
    double S = n / (double) d;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        n += 2;
        d -= 2;
        signal = -signal;
        S += signal * n/(double)d;
    }
    printf("%f", S);
}
```

I think you're missing `S` is a `double` number. `int/double = double`, but youre assign this math in a `int` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Different things to say about your code.

First you cannot use an integer for your sum since you want a floating point result.

Then as mentioned in comments you are using successive operations that result in not changing the variable

```
n+=2; n-=2;
```

You could simply do something like :

```
double S = 0.0; int N=9;
for(i=0; i < N; ++i) {
   S += ( (i % 2 == 0)?(1.0):(-1.0) ) * (2.0*i+1)/(50-(2.0*i+1));
}
```

The instruction (i % 2 == 0)?(1.0):(-1.0) pick 1 if 'i' is even and -1 if 'i' is odd.

Finally if S is no longer an int you must change your printf with a floating point format like for example '%f'.